# rspec check if view is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this kind of code:

```
   shared_examples "admin common actions" do |resource|

      describe "logged admin" do
        login_admin

        describe 'GET #index' do
          it 'responds with 200' do
            get :index, :format => :html
            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

so I was expecting in case my view have some errors and doesn't render the test should fail cause server will return 500. In my case test pass when view is not rendered. I checked the url and it's ok. So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should add `render_views ` to your `describe`, but that will slow down your specs, do it only if you're gonna test the view as well. Take a look here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views.

Comment: If you are expecting 500 errors why are you testing for 200 response. What do you mean by you checked the url and it's ok? Does ok in this case mean the server responded with a 500 error code? How did you test this - by entering it in a browser? It would be helpful to see your other code related to this - for example the controller index code, the view, and the relevant information for the test.

Comment: so I checked the response object output http://pastie.org/10975039, the scope of the test is to see if all views are rendered without errors, I intentionally make an error in the view to let test fail, and it still not failing, when I try this view in browser I have 500 status returned

Comment: hmmm ok. perhaps it isn't testing the correct index it is calling? I note this is a shared example so I assume you are using this from multiple controller specs. try outputting `puts request.url` to ensure it matches the url that should be generating the 500 error.

Comment: ....http://test.host/admin/items.html
.....http://test.host/admin/module_tenants.html
....http://test.host/admin/tag_categories.html
.....http://test.host/admin/tags.html
....http://test.host/admin/tenants.html
....http://test.host/admin/users.html

so this is the output, the url are ok expect server it's not localhost but I think it's ok until it's tests. All url's should fail cause they use the same partial with error in it. When I pus the url in browser with localhost it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that rspec doesn't actually render views by default when running controller tests, in an effort to isolate unit testing of controller actions from rendering views. Ideally the rendering of views should be the concern of view specs.

However if you really want to test this in your controller you can tell rspec to render the view. This will not generate an internal web server 500 status code, it will throw an exception, so you can ensure it is rendering the view correctly by testing that no exception is raised as opposed to testing for status 500.

```
shared_examples "admin common actions" do |resource|
  describe "logged admin" do
    login_admin

    describe 'GET #index' do
      it 'responds with 200' do
        get :index, :format => :html
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      end

      context 'when rendering view' do
        render_views

        it 'renders the view' do
          expect { get :index, :format => :html }.to_not raise_error
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I still have the same result, all tests pass

Comment: hmmm how odd ... the code above was tested and found to behave correctly for me. I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: maybe there is another way to check if view is rendered ok? not from controller spec for example

Comment: You should look into rspec view specs ... don't think you can check if the view is actually rendered or not but you can ensure that elements of the page exist - it they don't then obviously the rendering of the view failed in some way.